# python regex capture groups

Tags: python, regex, capture-group

I'm trying to write a regex pattern which will either match a number or a number and a trailing string. So **match** should ouput:

```
Matching "string100":      [('100', '')]
Matching "string900_TYPE": [('900', 'TYPE')]
```

But instead, I get:

```
Matching "string100":      [('100', '')]
Matching "string900_TYPE": [('900', ''), ('', 'TYPE')]
```

The idea is to have the number as the first item in the tuple and the "TYPE" as the second, so I can easily determine whether "TYPE" exists in a tuple or not (second tuple item is empty --> '').

**Code:**

```
import re


stringList = ["string100", "string900_TYPE"]
pattern = r"(\d{3})|\w(TYPE)"

for string in stringList:
    match = re.findall(pattern, string)
    print('Matching "' + string + '":\t', match)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Like that: `(\d{3})(?:_(\w+))?`. Don't use an alternation, describe the full string.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: That did it. Thank you!

Comment: The pattern can actually be simplified to `+(\d{3})_?(\w+)?` which requires less steps for the regex engine. Is there any reason for using a non-capturing group around the subgroup `(\w+)` ?

Comment: If you use `(\d{3})_?(\w+)?` (note there must be no `+` at the start) then you may also match `123_`. `(\d{3})(?:_(\w+))?` is best here since `(?:_(\w+))?` makes the whole sequence of patterns optional.

Comment: The `+` must have slipped in somehow... `123_` does not seem to be captured, though.

Comment: Ok, I see your point. Any number longer than three digits will also match the 4th or more digit and `_`

Answer (score 1):

`(\d{3})(?:_(\w+))?`will do the trick. (Thanks to @Casimir et Hippolyte)

It is also more robust than using a simpler pattern like `(\d{3})_?(\w+)?` (thanks to @Wiktor Stribiżew)